# How to define font when google font does not work

Tags: css, fonts, safari

I need a solution.. I am using google fonts on my website, but it is not working in safari, how can I tell the browser to use a different style when the font is not working? Here is my css code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans); 
    h2{ 
    font-family: 'Pontano Sans', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    }
```

I just want to have another css rule like this, but without it overriding the above rule:

```
h2{        
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: #666; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
```

Comment: What does the safari do? Does it not use the alternative font, *sans-serif*, as specified?

Comment: yes it does, but I need to change the size when it defaults to sans-serif... to 12px instead of 15px...

Comment: @Yogu I think liveandream wants an entire different set of rules to apply if the font isn't working. liveandream: Maybe you should be asking why it's not working in the first place, have you tried other linking methods? Regardless, you can't do this with just CSS, you'll need to resort to javascript. Probably using something like [this](http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the web-fonts loader capabilities to handle scenarios where fonts are not loaded.
that way, you can specify different styles based on the load state (active / inactive / loading).

see the [web-fonts loader reference on loading states](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader#Styles) (and [on github](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader)).